# What's the math behind the setRotateM function in android.opengl.matrix?

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es, rotational-matrices, euler-angles

There is a [`setRotateM`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/opengl/Matrix.java#Matrix.setRotateEulerM%28float%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cfloat%2Cfloat%2Cfloat%29) function in `android.opengl.matrix` package and it

> Converts Euler angles to a rotation matrix.

The principal part of the implementation is :

```
rm[rmOffset + 0]  =   cy * cz;
rm[rmOffset + 1]  =  -cy * sz;
rm[rmOffset + 2]  =   sy;
rm[rmOffset + 3]  =  0.0f;

rm[rmOffset + 4]  =  cxsy * cz + cx * sz;
rm[rmOffset + 5]  = -cxsy * sz + cx * cz;
rm[rmOffset + 6]  =  -sx * cy;
rm[rmOffset + 7]  =  0.0f;

rm[rmOffset + 8]  = -sxsy * cz + sx * sz;
rm[rmOffset + 9]  =  sxsy * sz + sx * cz;
rm[rmOffset + 10] =  cx * cy;
rm[rmOffset + 11] =  0.0f;

rm[rmOffset + 12] =  0.0f;
rm[rmOffset + 13] =  0.0f;
rm[rmOffset + 14] =  0.0f;
rm[rmOffset + 15] =  1.0f;
```

where `cx = cos(angleOnX), sz = sin(angleOnZ) etc.`

This bunch of code will give a 4x4 matrix:

```
[  cy*cz, cx*sz + cx*cz*sy, sx*sz - cz*sx*sy, 0]
[ -cy*sz, cx*cz - cx*sy*sz, cz*sx + sx*sy*sz, 0]
[     sy,           -cy*sx,            cx*cy, 0]
[      0,                0,                0, 1]
```

---

While, given rotation matrices around x, y, z axis respectively

```
Rx = [ 1,  0,   0, 0]
     [ 0, cx, -sx, 0]
     [ 0, sx,  cx, 0]
     [ 0,  0,   0, 1]

Ry = [  cy, 0, sy, 0]
     [   0, 1,  0, 0]
     [ -sy, 0, cy, 0]
     [   0, 0,  0, 1]

Rz = [ cz, -sz, 0, 0]
     [ sz,  cz, 0, 0]
     [  0,   0, 1, 0]
     [  0,   0, 0, 1]
```

The most similar composition I could find is

```
(Rx * Ry * Rz)^T = Rz^T * Ry^T * Rx^T = 
[  cy*cz, cx*sz + cz*sx*sy, sx*sz - cx*cz*sy, 0]
[ -cy*sz, cx*cz - sx*sy*sz, cz*sx + cx*sy*sz, 0]
[     sy,           -cy*sx,            cx*cy, 0]
[      0,                0,                0, 1]
```

Between android's implementation `R` and raw multiplication `Rxyz^T`,
there are slight differences in R(1,2) R(1,3) R(2,2) R(2,3) components, where `cx` and `sx` are switched.

Considering `android.opengl.matrix` is a widely-applied, time-tested package, I must have done something wrong.

I have two questions:
1. How this difference happens?
2. Why it is `(Rx * Ry * Rz)^T`? I suppose it was `Rz * Ry * Rx`

Answer (score -2):

question 1:  there is only one result in a right handed system using row or column vectors for a particuar order of rotations. so one of the formulas is wrong. maybe you included some terms from the projection matrix.

question 2: it's in x,y,z order because the rotations are done in that order (or the reverse).

the android version's difference *might* be due to the gui being a left handed system.

Comment: Could you elaborate where you see this happening? I can't find the change you describe in ops code. As far as I can see, `sx` is switched by `cx`.  Changing from `cos(x)` to `sin(x)` has (in my oppinion) nothing to do with commutativiy? If you are refering to question 2, the these are matrices which are not commutative.

Comment: [  cy*cz, cx*sz + cx*cz*sy, sx*sz - cz*sx*sy, 0] and  cy*cz, cx*sz + cz*sx*sy, sx*sz - cx*cz*sy, 0]

Comment: I still don't see any term here where only the multiplication order has changed. They are either identical or at least one sin has changed to cos.

Comment: First one of the formula is from `android.opengl.matrix` and the second one is calculated with matlab symbolic toolbox. I can't see which one is wrong, hence the question.

Comment: maybe due to left handed system in gui?

Comment: how did you get the text strings like: "cx" into a matlab matrix?

Comment: Using [symbolic toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html), it's quite easy to do that. @RayTayek.